# Set Map options after construction?

Tags: openlayers-2

I want to be able to set and change Openlayers.Map options after construction, but my results are not expected. Can anyone point out problems with my approach or suggest better way if possible?

http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.OpenLayers.Map

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
map.options = {
                projection: 'EPSG:3112',
                displayProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                units: 'm',
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-3237313.46,-5312745.84,3019649.82,-876762.78),                
                resolutions: [12288,6144,3072,1536,768,384]
                };
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind:
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.setOptions

```
    map.setOptions({
        projection: 'EPSG:3112',
        displayProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        units: 'm',
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-3237313.46,-5312745.84,3019649.82,-876762.78),            
        resolutions: [12288,6144,3072,1536,768,384]
        });
```